# ddply: Data frame column ' ' not supported by rbind.fill

Tags: r, plyr

When using ddply function in plyr package of R, I meet a problem. I have been searching for a long time on net, but in vain.

#### Here is database and R code:

This is tempdata:

[image]

This is the code:

```
count <- function(x){
  i <- which(x >= 250)
  first <- i[diff(i, 2)==2]
  len <- length(union(as.character(union(first, first+1)), first+2))
  data.frame(count = len)
  }

countResult <- ddply(tempdata, .(number, year), summarise, count(max_temp))
```

This is the error:

```
Error in allocate_column(df[[var]], nrows, dfs, var) : 
  Data frame column 'count(max_temp)' not supported by rbind.fill
```

Comment: can you attached the above temp data? What is your purpose of function count?